# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory Getting error in android app using titanium

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile

Trying to run a basic app using titanium on windows it was running perfectly but suddenly it started giving error in the `build.log` file

```
[INFO] logfile = C:\Users\sfarid\workspace\CNS PCC\build.log
[INFO] Building CNS PCC for Android ... one moment
[INFO] Titanium SDK version: 3.0.0 (12/12/12 18:49 a5894b3)
[INFO] Waiting for the Android Emulator to become available
[ERROR] Timed out waiting for android.process.acore
[INFO] Fastdev server running, deploying in Fastdev mode
[INFO] Copying CommonJS modules...
[INFO] Copying project resources..
[INFO] Force including all modules...
[INFO] Force including all modules...
[INFO] Compiling Javascript Resources ...
[INFO] Compiling localization files
[ERROR] Exception occured while building Android project:
[ERROR] Traceback (most recent call last):
[ERROR]   File "C:\Users\sfarid\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.0.GA\android\builder.py", line 2376, in <module>
[ERROR]     builder.build_and_run(False, avd_id, debugger_host=debugger_host)
[ERROR]   File "C:\Users\sfarid\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.0.GA\android\builder.py", line 2125, in build_and_run
[ERROR]     self.manifest_changed = self.generate_android_manifest(compiler)
[ERROR]   File "C:\Users\sfarid\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.0.GA\android\builder.py", line 1056, in generate_android_manifest
[ERROR]     shutil.copy(icon_path, dest_icon)
[ERROR]   File "C:\Users\sfarid\AppData\Local\Titanium Studio\plugins\com.appcelerator.titanium.python.win32_1.0.0.1338515509\python\lib\shutil.py", line 116, in copy
[ERROR]     copyfile(src, dst)
[ERROR]   File "C:\Users\sfarid\AppData\Local\Titanium Studio\plugins\com.appcelerator.titanium.python.win32_1.0.0.1338515509\python\lib\shutil.py", line 81, in copyfile
[ERROR]     with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
[ERROR] IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: **u'C:**\\Users\\sfarid\\workspace\\CNS PCC\\build\\android\\bin\\assets\\Resources\\appicon.png'
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
```

it re-generates the log file every time i run it and add `u`that become the reason of error.

This is main error

[ERROR] IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: **u'C:**\Users\sfarid\workspace\CNS PCC\build\android\bin\assets\Resources\appicon.png'
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1

I am new to titanium kindly help me.

Comment: one time i tried to remove that u and run it, it worked fine, but now its not running ... :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the tiapp.xml file; changing the version from 1.0 to 1.1 for example. I don't think that it's copying over the necessary files, and a change to tiapp.xml forces it to recreate the class file.